# Is "mesnomer" the Latin equivalent of the English word "misnomer"?

Tags: vocabulary, english

At first, I thought "misnomer" was an English word adapted from Latin (still learning, as you can see). Yet, it seems it does not exist in Latin. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misnomer):

> From Anglo-Norman mesnomer, noun use of Anglo-Norman and Old French verb mesnomer (“to name incorrectly”), from mes- (“mis-”) + nomer (“to name”) (from Latin nōmināre).

So, given this assertion, would not the Latin equivalent be "mesnomer"? However, Wiktionary does not yield an entry for such word. Neither does [S&L dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=mesnomer&lang). Why is such not a word? Am I incorrectly understanding the above quoted text?

Comment: If you read carefully, the only mention of Latin is for the verb _nominare_, which is not in _mesnomer_. Apparently _nomer_ is Old French for Latin _nominare_.

Comment: The prefix _mes_/_mis_ is, as I understand, from Latin _minus_ (in the sense 'not fully, perfectly, or adequately'); so etymologically, the Latin equivalent – at least for the French verb that is the source of the English noun _misnomer_ – would be the phrase _minus nominare_.

Comment: @Rafael Very true.

Comment: @cnread Thanks. Can you put this as an answer?

Comment: But if _minus nominare_ is a verb, then what is the noun misnomer? Some quick digging reveals the non-classical _transnominatio_ might work. It usually means "metonymy," which in turn means referring to one object though the use of one of its qualities. This makes sense for a misnomer. Take, for instance, oxidation. Oxidation was given that name because it was originally thought to occur only with respect to oxygen (named because of quality), but we now know that it applies to more scenarios than that (a misnomer). Of course, not all metonymies are misnomers, so do with that what you will.

Comment: @cnread The sources I looked at seem to think it comes from Frankish<Proto-Germanic<PIE, not from *minus*.

Comment: @brianpck. Interesting. My dictionary tells me that there are 2 _mis_ prefixes, one from OTeut and one from Latin _minus_ via OF. Their meanings even overlap somewhat. It is quite an old dictionary, though (1955). Still, if it's accurate, I'm inclined to think that, because the _nomer_ part of _misnomer_ is from French, the _mis_ prefix is, in this instance, the latter.

Comment: @SamK: In Sallust's _Bellum Catilinae_, Cato says 'iam pridem equidem nos vera vocabula rerum amisimus'; so perhaps something like _falsum vocabulum_ would work. Or, Cicero speaks in multiple places of _certa et/ac propria vocabula_ (e.g., _Pro Caecina_ 51: 'an hoc dubium est quin neque verborum tanta copia sit...res ut omnes suis certis ac propriis vocabulis nominentur...'); so perhaps _incertum atque alienum_ [= _non proprium_] _vocabulum_ is another possibility. I myself like the simple phrase _vocabulum alienum_ ('a term that [really, properly] belongs to something else').

Comment: @cnread I think your comments are for a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

No, *mesnomer* is not a Latin word. The quotations only say that it is a Old French word.